# Log particular systemd service logs only to syslog bypasing journald

Tags: systemd, syslog, systemd-journald

For a while looking for a solution that with systemd tools will give me an opportunity to bypass the journal and log directly to syslog. Potentially that can be also filtered, but only on journal not on syslog of course.

So far I can't make it right.
My system is OL8 with systemd 239-68.

What was already tried:

```
[Service]
...
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=my_service
...
```

This gives dual logging to journal and to syslog.
Second try was set `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` to `append`.

Do not want to use above, since messages sent that way are raw with no identifier or timestamp that probably needs to be set by the sender (application) and this is out of my jurisdiction.

I know that I can do it using `ExecStart` and `2>&1` with logger in separate script but really it is last resort since it is informal.

Also saw these two topics:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6432

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/24058

But none of them address specifically the above problem.

Can you point me to any other ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: According to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601073/471376), add directives with file path syntax like `StandardOutput=file:/home/user/log1.log`, or `StandardOutput=append:/home/user/log1.log`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon Please read my question again. You will notice that `append` is covered there and why I would not like to use it.

Comment: You tried `StandardOutput=syslog` for syslog.  The recommend syntax for is `StandardOutput=file:/home/user/log1.log`.

Comment: ... so I will explain again - `append` is useless considering my needs - it depends on application raw output so there is no timestamp and application identifier. That's why I want to go with syslog. Proposed `file` is similar to `append` , second one will not delete content of log between service restarts.
Anyway - both `append` and `file` need scripting inside `ExecStart` or application output change. That is why I do not want to go with it. I will modify my question to point it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to connect the stdout of the program to a Unix domain socket. Configure rsyslogd to read this socket, and to add a timestamp before doing any filtering and eventually writing it to a file. For example, add these lines to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
module(load="imptcp")
input(type="imptcp" path="/tmp/mysocket1" name="my1")
template(name="outfmt" type="string" string="%timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %inputname% %rawmsg%\n")
if $inputname=="my1" then {
  action(type="omfile" file="myoutput" template="outfmt")
}
```

When rsyslogd is restarted it will create a socket `/tmp/mysocket1`. In
the systemd service file use

```
StandardOutput=file:/tmp/mysocket1
```

By default, `StandardError` inherits the same socket as `StandardOutput`.

Now all the lines written by the program will be read by rsyslogd and can
be handled, for example by adding the time received timestamp, the name
"my1" we gave to the input, and the rawmsg.  (The rsyslog documentation
suggests that systemd actually ignores the timestamp in a message anyway,
and uses its own internal time, so this is not unusual).

If you need to distinguish between several programs, they would each need
to have their own named socket. Instead of testing the `inputname`, it
might be preferable to enclose the setup in a ruleset. Of course, you can
also create and run a separate dedicated rsyslogd daemon with its own
config file.

Comment: This is what I need, have only one service to log that way so it is not complicated and fits my need for minimal shell scripting. Meanwhile found that with systemd > 245 I can Also use different, dedicated namespace configured with minimal space redirecting logs from service using  `LogNamespace` directive.